# Transform performance

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview

How is performance on transforming a uiview?

I have a advanced uiview on ipad that I want to show in a smaller scale on iphone.
The easy hack is to do a transform on the uiview:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.5, 0.5);
```

This fits the view very well, but how about performance?

The alternative would be to make every item in the view able to scale according to the device.

Is transform considered bad practice when it comes to scaling uiviews?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a GPU accelerated operation there's no performance downside (at least none that would matter in real life).

But note that you may not access the `frame` property any more, it's now considered invalid: instead, you need to access/modify `bounds` and `center`. I've had problems with AutoLayout and transforms due to this, but YMMV.

From the [`transform` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW4):

> **Warning:** If this property is not the identity transform, the value of the *frame* property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

So if you can live with those restriction there's nothing wrong with applying a transform (rotation and translation are also fine).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have *no* performance penalty for that at all. Why?

The trick of transformations is that you can concatenate them into a single transformation and then apply this single transformation to the output. So if you have three transformations

T1, T2, T3

concatenated, every point will *not* be transformed three times like this:

P' = P × T1 × T2 × T3

making transformation slower. Instead when applying a transformation, these are multiplied to a new one

T' = T1 × T2 × T3

and then this new transformation is applied to the output:

P' = P × T'

So there is no penalty for every transformations used. (There is a very, very small penalty, when transformation is set and it is a penalty you get one time for the whole view: Don't care.)

Moreover in most cases there is always one transformation used: The unit transformation. (Is this the correct english term?) The reason for this is that it is easier in code to simply use a "do nothing transformation" instead of asking whether there is a transformation. Additionally the system can set transformations for its own use, i. e. panning, turning 90° and so on.

So at all: Don't care about that. I would not expect any penalty you can measure.

BTW: Donald Knuth.

Comment: The fact that you can combine several transformations into a single transformation does not tell you whether you get a performance penalty for using them or not. If the transformations would need to be applied _on the CPU_ there would be a (possibly noticeable) penalty.

Comment: No, because typically the system applies its own final transformation (at least the unit transformation) to the output. And there is no difference for applying the systems transformation concatenated to the apps transformation or solely applying the system transformation. To every output exactly one transformation is applied.

Comment: If the transformation is the unit transformation (the default) I'm pretty sure the system won't do anything at all. After all, it would be an expensive NOP if it did try to apply the unit transformation, wouldn't it? So the question is: what is the penalty when the transformation is not the unit transformation? And again: the penalty would likely be noticeable if the calculations were done on the _CPU_ instead of the _GPU_ which is highly optimized for these things (and the reason why CALayers were introduced in the first place: to offload these operations to the GPU).

Comment: I do not think that if it is the unit transformation nothing is done. Testing for that seems to be much more expensive. (Testing for simply NULL would be easier.) And it would be worthless: The system has to apply a transformation at all, if the view is not exactly the screen buffer (panning, orientation, …). So you get the penalty even you do *not* apply any transformation yourself. And yes, this is the reason, why GPU has been introduced. Because you get the penalty *everytime*, even you do not apply a transformation your own.

Comment: You think testing for the 6 (CGAffineTransform) or 12 (CATransform3D) values is more expensive than actually iterating (in this case without modifying) pixel values of a buffer? Now you've totally lost me…

Comment: BTW: In former times (aka no GPU calculation) the system became slow, when you have masses of subviews, because the *system* has to apply transformations for that subviews. (Each one time.) But you got *no* penalty, if you has much output, because the system *already needed* to do transformation. So it was a "performance hack" to use less subviews and more output per view.

Comment: @DarkDust Of course it is, because the test will fail in 99,99999 % of all cases.

Comment: What? Almost _every_ view has the identity transform! But I believe we don't understand each other (reden aneinander vorbei ;-). Anyway, none of this discussion will help the OP. Bottom line of both of us: using a transformation on a UIView won't bring a measurable performance penalty.

Comment: @DarkDust But the output has to go to the screen, not to the view. So it has to be transformed anyway.

Comment: @DarkDust BTW: This is the reason why you cannot use `-drawRect…:` immediately. Do you remember the discussion?

Comment: OK, I'll bite: as far as I understand you can regard each view as a kind of OpenGL plane with a texture. The system calls your `drawRect:` to actually fill that texture. What does this have to do with the transformation discussion? Except that I now get what you've meant with "there's always a transformation applied" (position/size/orientation of the plane). As I've already said, this discussion has moved in a direction that is not helping the OP so this will be my last post on this thread.

Comment: Because the system has to set-up this process. For example: The plane needs to know its transformation. (And many other things has to be done.) In earlier times (when CALayer wasn't  there), the system set-up the  final transformation. (Inside the GPU starting with 10.3 or so.) There are manning things "around" sending drawRect… including mapping of the view, its layer and so on to the screen. (BTW: This is the reason why transformations are concatenated to the beginning of the transformation chain, which is surprising when you recognize it the first time.)